# Unable to expose/show a lwc in a flow screen

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to expose a lwc as a part of flow screen, below is my lwc config file which is used in my component.
But the I am unable to see the component in the flow screen custom component section, am i missing something here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Best Component Ever</masterLabel>
    <description>This is a demo component.</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Just check if you find any component with name **Best Component Ever** because you have defined masterlabel in the configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons here:-

1. check the [flow Metadata API version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm). Support of Lightning Web component in Flows enabled after [winter 20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_solutions.htm). Make sure your flow API version is later than that or winter 20.
2. Just check if you find any component with name **Best Component Ever** because you have defined masterLabel in the configuration file. Many got confused with it and keep looking for the component with component name.

Comment: I think the flow API version fixed it.